# Pattern name special characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get a pattern which says:

Only numbers a-z A-Z 0-9 . + - %

Are wrong, its my code:

```
String regex = "[^a-zA-Z0-9_\\.+-\\%]";
```

I'm getting exception
Illegal character range near index 17
at 17 index i have %, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do need to escape `-` unless you meant the symbols `+` to `%`

Comment: @pustypawel Please note that the double-backslashes in your code above were not apparent until I formatted it as code - if you are posting code, indent by 4 or surround with backticks.

Comment: The regex is wrong, since it includes `_` and your stated requirements don't. And what does "Only *numbers*" mean when you then say that `a-z` (not numbers) and `0-9` (numbers) is valid?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to escape `%` in a regular expression. Remove the `\` before it.

You also shouldn't be escaping the `.`. There's no need to do that inside a character class: inside a character class, it means the literal `.` character, not "any character".

But you *do* need to escape the `-`, where you mean the literal `-`, rather than a character range.

```
String regex = "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.+\\-%]";
```

Comment: Based on anubhava answer I think that i don't need to escape - character if it is on the end of expression? Am I right?

Comment: @pustypawel It would appear so. I would recommend against doing that, though, just in case you decide to add some more characters to the character class - you could accidentally turn the `-` into a range.

Comment: This can be shorten as" [^\w\.\+\-\%]"

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting exception Illegal character range

This is due to presence of **unescaped hyphen in the middle of character class** that acts as a range. You can place unescaped hyphen at first or last position inside character class or else you will need to escape it.

You can use this regex:

```
String regex = "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.+%-]";
```

or:

```
String regex = "[^\\w.+%-]";
```

There is no need to escape DOT or `%` inside the character class.